# Access sensors and camera of Android device from shell

Tags: camera, remote-control, ssh, sensors

I have logged in to my Android phone through SSH [installed SSH client in Android and through Putty from Windows]. Now I can access all the directories like `root`, `dev`, `etc`, of the phone.

Can someone tell me what's the native method to access the devices and sensors of the phone? I mean, how can I control say, the camera, just from this Linux shell terminal of the phone?

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the network for more than 5 years, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but since android isn't so different than the underlying Linux system, you might be able to do the same thing as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2302/can-i-pipe-dev-video-over-ssh). The device file name might be different though and you might need to be rooted.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the simplest method is to use [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam) app. It has HTTP API so you can do all kinds of things with it.

To be fair, I'd also really like to know if there's a way with just shell.